# Why instance variable to be final?

Tags: java, immutability, final

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306651/why-would-one-declare-an-immutable-class-final-in-java) about immutable objects and was left with a question regarding immutable objects and final field:

Why do we need instance variable in immutable class to be final?

For example, consider this immutable class:

```
public final class Immutable 

{

  private final int someVal;

  public Immutable(int someVal)
 {

    this.someVal= someVal;
  }

  public int getVal() {

    return val;
}

}
```

If in the above code there is no set methods and the instance variable is set only within the constructor, why is it required that the instance variable is declared final?

Comment: read the cited question again, not the instance variables have to be final but the class.

Comment: yeah I read that, but my question was why instance variables in that class should be final?

Comment: Maybe it's about that: It does not **have** to be final, but it **should** be final (to make unambiguously clear that it will not be modified).

Comment: @Marco13 its not required to make instance variable to be final, but i need to make it final.So its just a good practice of coding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no *requirement* as such to make the variable `final`. However, when it is true that you explicitly intend to never change the variable, it is often good practice to make it `final`, since that not only enforces the invariant against typos or other mistakes, but also declares the intent that it be immutable to, eg., other programmers or yourself.

If the variable were `public`, then you would strictly need to make it `final` in order to ensure that interfacing code cannot change its value.

Do note that the question you link is not directly related, however, as it discusses *classes* that are `final`, rather than variables. Making a class `final` means that it cannot be inherited from, not that it is immutable. There is certainly a case to be made for taking heed of the contents of that question and its answer when making immutable objects, however; but it is a *separate* question nonetheless.

Answer (score 6):

By marking all of a class' fields `final`, you make it clear that you intend your class to be immutable.

Suppose you have the following class:

```
public class Immutable {
    private int value;

    public Immutable (int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue () {
        return value;
    }
}
```

There is no setter method, so one could easily assume that this class is immutable. Which it is, for now. But eventually your class will be modified by some other programmer, and this programmer might add some methods to your class:

```
public class Immutable {
    private int value;

    public Immutable (int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue () {
        return value;
    }

    public void doSomething () {
        value++;
    }
}
```

It is quite easy to inadvertently add a method that modifies the state of your object if the fields are not `final`. By marking them `final`, this other programmer will get a compile error when he tries to modify the field, and will have to ask himself why is this field `final`, and does his modification breaks the contract of this class.

One could argue that the Javadoc should be used to document that said class is immutable, but quite frankly, not everyone reads the Javadoc. Making the code speak for itself is better in my opinion.

Comment: That was a good explanation from programming point of view such as when my code gets replaced after some time.

Comment: In the question your linked to, there's a very good point about marking your class `final`, which you should take into consideration.

Answer (score 1):

In immutable class you can not change the state of it's property/field. Generally it is done by not providing setter method to the client code of the class.

And the combination of `static final` keyword is used to make a variable constant. A variable declared final can never be change it's value once it has been initialized.

Since in immutable class you never need to change the property/field state, so it is better to make it final.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers are wrong.

To be immutable an object must declare all properties as `final`.

There are certain guarantees that the Java Memory Model makes for final fields that protect them from returning incorrect default values when there are data races between threads.

See example 17.5-2 in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5-110.

Comment: explain your answer here link are not sufficient

Comment: Don't just provide links buddy. Give some explanation too.