# In Java Concurrency in Practice by Brian Goetz, Why point class is Immutable which is used by DelegatingVehicleTracker

Tags: java, concurrency, immutability

Please let me know why the below class is Immutable as discussed in Java concurrency in practice - By Brian Goetz

```
@Immutable
public class Point {
    public final int x, y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

As the class is not final, any class can extend it.But why it is still Immutable?

Comment: Could have made it final, but that's be the only change.

Comment: I think it must be clearer to say that Point interface (aka "abstraction") is not mutable (`x` and `y` attributes) whereas sub-classes can add additional states which can be mutable (or not).

Answer (score 6):

It's immutable because once you construct an instance of it, you cannot change its internal state in any way. That's because it has no setters and the x and y are final i.e. you cannot mutate/change the x or y value.

**EDIT** (check that example):

```
package test;

public class Test002 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point1 p1 = new Point1(4, 10);
        consume(p1);
    }

    public static void consume(Point p){
        System.out.println("=============");
        System.out.println(p.x);
        System.out.println(p.y);

        if (p instanceof Point1){
            System.out.println("=============");
            Point1 p1 = (Point1)p;
            p1.setX(5);
            p1.setY(11);
            System.out.println(p.x);
            System.out.println(p.y);
            System.out.println(p1.getX());
            System.out.println(p1.getY());          
        }
    }

}



class Point {
    public final int x, y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

class Point1 extends Point {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Point1(int x, int y) {
        super(x, y);
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

Comment: But any class can  extend it and apply it's own getter and setter and use that class instead when point class is required.

Comment: If so the sub-class is mutable but that does not mean that Point is mutable. Right? Make a few tests, think about them, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Please follow the link .You will come to know my doubts.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306651/why-would-one-declare-an-immutable-class-final-in-java

Comment: It's weakly immutable. If you do anything that relies on its immutability (e.g. a `Point` is passed to the constructor of another class, without a defensive copy, and then used for calculating that class's `hashCode`) - and you are passed a mutable subclass of it, your code may be broken.

Comment: @PramodKishore Note this comment there: "You don't need to make the entire class final just the getter... public final int getValue()". Here we have no getter and x,y are final. So we're covered IMHO. Read carefully all comments after templatetypedef's answer.

Comment: Also note this comment, it says it all: " templatetypedef Sep 6 '12 at 19:45". "The method that you pass the Mutable object into won't change the object. The concern is that that method might assume that the object is immutable when it really isn't..." That's it. So `Immutable` is still immutable IMHO :)

Comment: @peter.petrov Let's assume we have a class that extends Point class.public class Point1 extends Point{
 private int  x;
  private int y;
 public Point1(int x, int y) {
  super(x, y);
  this.x=x;
  this.y=y;
 }
 
 

public void setX(int x) {
 this.x = x;
}
public void setY(int y) {
 this.y = y;
}


public int getX() {
 return x;
}


public int getY() {
 return y;
}
}
  as Point1 is an instance of Point , we can pass Point1 when Point is required.And then all the bad things will  happen.

Comment: @PramodKishore I don't see what bad can happen, you're missing something here. See that example which I added. Even if you mutate the instance, you're mutating the internal state of the Point1 part of it, not of the Point part of it. Note that in the method `consume` even such code as `if (p instanceof Point1)` will normally not be there, as this method knows nothing about Point1, it deals with Point only. But even if it's there - what is the problem? I don't see it. Point is still immutable.

Comment: @peter public static void main(String[] args) {
  Map<Point,String> pointMap=new HashMap<Point, String>();
        Point1 p1 = new Point1(4, 10);
        pointMap.put(p1, "x");
        for(Point p:pointMap.keySet()){
         Point1 P1=(Point1)p;
         System.out.println(P1.getX());
         System.out.println(P1.getY());
        }
        p1.setX(5);// A thread came along and changed the value
        p1.setY(9);// x and y
        for(Point p:pointMap.keySet()){
         Point1 p2=(Point1)p;
         System.out.println(p2.getX());
         System.out.println(p2.getY());
        }
    }

Comment: @PramodKishore The Point part of the object is still not changed. You are setting and getting and printing the x,y values from the Point1 part of your object, not from the Point part of it. This is what is confusing you.

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms – *No*, this class is not immutable. But things are more complicated than that.

In his book Brian Goetz says nothing about *immutable classes*. He talking about *immutable objects*. Object called immutable if:

- its state cannot be modified after construction;
- all its fields are final;
- it's properly constructed (`this` reference doesn't escape during construction).

There is indeed no mention of `final` class requirement. But this is because we are talking about objects of given type (for example `Point`) at runtime. Objects can't change their type in runtime, so there is no need for `final` class requirement. If we know objects state doesn't change at runtime it's effectively immutable. In this sense **objects** of type `Point` are indeed immutable.

But note that in Listing 3.11 (Chapter *3.4 Immutablility*) immutable object provided as an example, and its class defined as `final`.

The problem I thinks there is some confusion between *immutable object* and *immutable type (class)*.

In reality for application to be correctly multithreaded, all clients should be aligned in terms of shared objects usage policy. This is where you need *immutable types*. Because regardless of `Point` objects immutability, there could be mutable, and as a consequence, non thread-safe `Point` subtypes. And if you have any, Liskov substitution principle is broken. `Point` subtypes should not degrade on provided guarantees.

For a type to be immutable it must obey following rules:

- class state cannot be modified after construction;
- all its fields are final;
- it's properly constructed (`this` reference doesn't escape during construction);
- **all subtypes of a class should be immutable or class should be `final`**;
- **all supertypes of a class should be immutable**.

This is basically same restrictions as described by Brian Goetz, but in context of compile-time rather than runtime. If you accomplish this all objects created from those immutable-types will be thread-safe.

So, write *immutable classes*, and yes, `Point` type should be `final`.