# Code Example for how a Mutable subclass object can cause issue when Immutable object is expected

Tags: java, string, immutability, final, mutable

I was going through this question 
[Why would one declare an immutable class final in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306651/why-would-one-declare-an-immutable-class-final-in-java)

I understood this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306651/why-would-one-declare-an-immutable-class-final-in-java?answertab=active#tab-top) but need a code example.

I wrote it but has some doubts and would appreciate if someone can help.

```
    public class Immutable {
            private final int value;

            public Immutable(int value) {
                this.value = value;
            }

            public int getValue() {
                return value;
            }

            public boolean equals(Object obj) { 
                return (obj instanceof Immutable 
                          && getValue() == ((Immutable) obj).getValue());
                }

            public int hashCode() { 
                  int hash = 1;
                  hash = hash * 31 + value;
                  return hash;
                }
        }

        public class Mutable extends Immutable {
            private int realValue;

            public Mutable(int value) {
                super(value);

                realValue = value;
            }

            public int getValue() {
                return realValue;
            }
            public void setValue(int newValue) {
                realValue = newValue;
            }
        }

// test class main()
   Mutable key = new Mutable(30);
   Hashtable<Immutable, String> ht = new Hashtable<Immutable,String>();

   ht.put(new Immutable(10), "10");
   ht.put(new Immutable(20), "20");
   ht.put(key, "30");

   System.out.println("Hashcode : "+key.hashCode()+", \tKey : "+key.getValue()+" => Value : "+ht.get(key));

   key.setValue(40);
   System.out.println("Hashcode : "+key.hashCode()+", \tKey : "+key.getValue()+" => Value : "+ht.get(key));

Output : 
Hashcode : 61,  Key : 30 => Value : 30
Hashcode : 61,  Key : 40 => Value : 30
```

I can't relate the Answer given with this Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working because your `hashCode` method is using the final field `value` from the `Immutable` class directly instead of using the getter for the field. This field is not changed when using the `setValue` method from `Mutable` as this method works on the `realValue` field only.

If you change `hashCode` to

```
public int hashCode() { 
    int hash = 1;
    hash = hash * 31 + getValue(); // use getter here
    return hash;
}
```

You will observe the undesired behavior as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214714/mutable-vs-immutable-objects?rq=1).

It is important to note that your code is actually breaking the equals contract. As two instances of `Mutable` may be equal to each other but have different hashcodes...

Comment: I updated the equals method as : `public boolean equals(Object obj) { 
     return (obj instanceof Immutable && obj.hashCode() == this.hashCode() && getValue() == ((Immutable) obj).getValue());
     }`

Comment: This will fulfill the equals contract. However this is not really best practice. Consider reading [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java) on how to implement proper equals and hashcode methods.