# How to break immutability of String class , Could any one explain about below code?

Tags: java

what is the reason of String class to make "public class final String ". 
 below I have written an immutable class without the final keyword. could anyone can able to break this class immutability.

```
mport java.util.Date;

public class Person {

    private final String name;
    private final Date dob;

    public Person(String name, Date dob) {
        this.name = name;
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getName() {
        System.out.println("in person :" + name);
        return this.name;
    }

    public Date getDob() {
        System.out.println("in person :" + dob);
        return this.dob;
    }

}
```

Comment: I can subclass it and add another field that has a setter.

Comment: The code formatting is wrong. Please write your question as plain text before the code.

Comment: I want to know the reason how will break the immutability of above code if we are not using final keyword with the class name.

Comment: It's funny that you call your class "immutable" although it provides access to mutable fields.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why would one declare an immutable class final in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12306651/why-would-one-declare-an-immutable-class-final-in-java)

Answer (score 4):

You haven't written a immutable class because the `final` modifier for the class is missing.
Or you need a `final` modifier for the methods `getName()` and `getDob()` so that this fields are immutable.

In your example it's still possible to "modify" the class with a subclass. For example:

```
public class EditablePerson extends Person {
    // create new fields for name and dob
    // this is possible because the private fields of the superclass are not visible
    private String name;
    private Date  dob;

    public EditablePerson(String name,Date dob){
        // call the constructor of the super-class with dummy-data
        super("garbage", null);
        this.name=name;
        this.dob=dob;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName(){
        System.out.println("in person :"+name);
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    @Override
    public Date getDob(){
        System.out.println("in person :"+dob);
        return this.dob;
    }

    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }
}
```

To test this:

```
Person p=new EditablePerson("P", new Date());
p.getName();
if(p instanceof EditablePerson) {
    ((EditablePerson)p).setName("Changed");
}
p.getName();
```

---

As [@Tom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3824919/tom) noted:

The class Person is also not immutable because it has a field with a mutable class (the class `Date` is mutable) which can be changed from the outside.

Here the example:

```
Person p=new Person("P",new Date());
p.getDob();
p.getDob().setTime(0l);
p.getDob()
```

Also read: [A Strategy for Defining Immutable Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html)

Comment: You don't need a subclass to modify the data.

Comment: I am adding some output of your code and enable to see the how my class object changing .

Comment: @Tom Sure you do. You can't modify the data in `Person`, since the fields are `final`.

Comment: Person p=new Person("P",new Date());
 p.getName();
 EditablePerson ed=new EditablePerson("E", new Date());
 ed.getName();
 p.getName();
 ed.setName("Setting new One");
 ed.getName();
 p.getName();
 
 Person p2=new EditablePerson("Child Object", new Date());
 p2.getName();
 ed.getName();
 p.getName();

Comment: in person :P
in person :E
in person :P
in person :Setting new One
in person :P
in person :Child Object
in person :Setting new One
in person :P

Comment: @Andreas Come on, you should be experienced enough to know that `Date` is mutable and it very well can be mutated by using the instance passed by `getDob`.

Comment: @Bharat I add the proper testcode to prove that person is not immutable.

Comment: @Tom If you want to cover the fallibility of `Date` being mutable, though almost everything uses it as-if it was immutable, then say so. That is a problem with `Date`, easily fixed by using `LocalDate` instead, and has nothing to do with the discussion about whether the lack of `final` makes the class mutable. Even adding `final` wouldn't fix the `Date` problem.

Comment: Making getter `final` doesn't make `Person` immutable either. @Tom is right that without subclassing `Person` is already technically mutable because `Date` field is not immutable.

Comment: @Andreas The whole premise of OP "I build an immutable class" is already wrong and not worth to further discuss since he doesn't seem to have the basic understanding of what he's doing anyway.

Comment: @Tom I read the question more like "is this class really immutable", and therefore we can show the OP all the mistakes which makes the class not immutable.

Comment: @devpuh Or we understand that this question has been asked several times before (here and on software engineering) and close this as a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

A class that is declared `final` cannot be used as a base class. Nobody can add attributes or methods to it. See also 
[Use of final class in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181578/use-of-final-class-in-java)

Comment: I am not asking like that if we are not using final with class name then there will be immutability or not if not then specify the reason with prove .

Comment: I don't have to prove anything to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MutablePerson extends Person {

    private Gender gender;
    public MutablePerson(String name,Date dob, Gender gender) {
        super(name, dob);
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public final Gender getGender() { return gender; }
    public final void setGender(Gender g) { gender = g; }

    // Override hashcodes and equals as required.
}

public Person getPerson() { return new MutablePerson("Richard", new Date(), Gender.MALE); }

Person person = getPerson(); // Cannot assume person is immutable.
```

There you go, this is no longer immutable.

Comment: `MutablePerson` is not immutable, that is true, but anyone using the object as a `Person` will see it as immutable, because nothing they can see will ever change. This is a bad example. [Answer by devpuh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48295117/5221149) shows how overriding the base class methods actually make the `Person` object appear mutable too.

Comment: @Andreas Anyone is free to cast it and manipulate it, and no exceptions will be thrown. When you assume that this is immutable because you see it is `Person` type, you are going to get mysterious symptoms later on (e.g. using that instance as a key of a hashmap).

Comment: You're right, *if* subclass overrides `hashCode` and `equals`. Your code doesn't. Still bad example. As subclass currently is written, anyone using the `MutablePerson` as a `Person` will never see any changes to the object, even if used as a key in a `HashMap`.

Comment: @Andreas I did say override hashcode and equals. I'm just lazy to write concrete implementation in the example.

Comment: If your point was that override `hashCode` and `equals` would make `Person` appear mutable, then you should have said so, and shown by writing them, and the `gender` stuff is then unnecessary, because it doesn't have anything to do with that. Your answer is all about `gender`, but that doesn't make the point you're trying to make. Still bad example.

Comment: https://fliprank.blogspot.com/2018/12/webtraffic-management-load-balancer.html?m=0